# Font Awesome Documentation License

Tags: font-awesome

Regarding font Awesome Licenses:

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/license/

Does the Documentation License apply if I am just referencing the code (CSS, and fonts (otf,eot,svg,ttf,woff?)

My guess is no.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of licensing, and is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. It may be appropriate for [programmers.se] instead, but you should check the guidelines for that site before posting there to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I would interpret it as well:

> Applies to all Font Awesome project files that are not a part of the Font or Code licenses.

In short, don't copy and paste the documentation (readme or any of the io site content) without attributing it back to FA.